# HAVING different between Sybase and Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

The following query worked in Sybase SQL: -

```
select id, version from local_tbl
group by id
having version < max(version)
```

It gets me all id's and versions except for the maximum.

When i try the same query in Postgres 9.1, i get the following error message: -

```
Error: ERROR: column "local_tbl.version" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

I can't put the version in the group by as i want all of the versions for an id.

How can i do the equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT id, version
FROM (
      select id, 
             version, 
             max(version) OVER (PARTITION BY id) as max_version
      from local_tbl ) sub
WHERE version < max_version
```

Comment: Why not just add `MAX(version) AS max_version` in the select query and add `version` to the `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: @Tikkes Because `MAX(version)` while grouping by `version` will always be equal to `version`.